# How to avoid using loginPopup or loginRedirect and silently get the authenticated

Tags: javascript, json, oauth-2.0, chatbot, azure-ad-msal

I want to avoid using the loginPopup or loginRedirect and get authenticated directly. I am using the below code. I am try to achieve SSO by hosting my chatbot on sharepoint website. As i have already login to my sharepoint website I need to avoid login again.

Current functionality, When i click on the chatbot icon i am getting a pop-up window on the current site. i.e. sharepoint and i am login again, I need to avoid this.

For complete code [click here](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerVirtualAgentsSamples/blob/master/BuildYourOwnCanvasSamples/3.single-sign-on/index.html)

```
function onSignInClick() {
  alert("Inside onSignInClick function");
  let requestObj = {
    scopes: ["user.read", 'openid', 'profile']
  };
  debugger;
  clientApplication.loginPopup(requestObj)
  .then(onSignin)
  .catch(function (error) { console.log(error) });
}

function onSignin(idToken) {
  let user = clientApplication.getAccount();
  document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = "Currently logged in as " + user.name;
  let requestObj1 = {
    scopes: ["user.read", 'openid', 'profile']
  };
}

var clientApplication;

(function () {
  var msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: '<client id>',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory id>'
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false
    }
  };
  if (!clientApplication) {
    clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
    //alert("Inside if clientApplication: " + JSON.parse(clientApplication));
  }
}());

(async function main() {
  // Add your BOT ID below
  var BOT_ID = "<Bot-Id>";
  var theURL = "https://powerva.microsoft.com/api/botmanagement/v1/directline/directlinetoken?botId=" + BOT_ID;
  //alert("before userId async function: " + JSON.parse(clientApplication));
  var userId = clientApplication.account?.accountIdentifier != null
    ? ("You-customized-prefix" + clientApplication.account.accountIdentifier).substr(0, 64)
    : (Math.random().toString() + Date.now().toString()).substr(0, 64)
  ;
  //debugger;
  alert("after userId async function: " + JSON.parse(userId));
  const { token } = await fetchJSON(theURL);
  const directLine = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token });
  const store = WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
      const { type } = action;
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
        dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: {
            name: 'startConversation',
            type: 'event',
            value: { text: "hello" }
        }
      });
      return next(action);
    }
    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
      const activity = action.payload.activity;
      let resourceUri;
      if (activity.from && activity.from.role === 'bot' && (resourceUri = getOAuthCardResourceUri(activity))) {
        exchangeTokenAsync(resourceUri)
        .then(function (token) {
          if (token) {
            directLine.postActivity({
              type: 'invoke',
              name: 'signin/tokenExchange',
              value: {
                id: activity.attachments[0].content.tokenExchangeResource.id,
                connectionName: activity.attachments[0].content.connectionName,
                token
              },
              "from": {
                id: userId,
                name: clientApplication.account.name,
                role: "user"
              }
            }).subscribe(
              id => {
                if (id === 'retry') {
                  // bot was not able to handle the invoke, so display the oauthCard
                  return next(action);
                }
                // else: tokenexchange successful and we do not display the oauthCard
              },
              error => {
                // an error occurred to display the oauthCard
                return next(action);
              }
            );
            return;
          }
          else
            return next(action);
        });
      }
      else
        return next(action);
    }
    else
      return next(action);
  });
  window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
      directLine: directLine,
      store,
      userID: userId,
      styleOptions
    },
    document.getElementById('webchat')
  );
})()
.catch(err => console.error("An error occurred: " + err));
```

Answer (score 0):

By your scenario to eliminate loginPopup or loginRedirect in autentication,I understood that you don't require user involvement to login. The possible solution for your scenario is to use [Client credential flow.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

Client Credential Flow does not require user login and can silently Sign-in with application permissions.

Please refer this [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2) which can help.

Comment: Hi @Hari/ @Nishant, Thank you for your reply. Can any changes be done on the code that I have shared in the post in order for me to achieve this? I did refer the link that was shared on the post and am not sure how to achieve this through my code. Any help with update/reference to the code that I have added is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Ram, your code is written for user interaction and it will not help you in silently login by changing it. Please go through code samples given by Microsoft which can help you.please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code).